# In Yii What is the difference between the $model define with and without function

Tags: yii, yii-components

In Yii What is the difference between the **$model = new Users and $model = new Users()** ?

Comment: no difference.both are same till the time you do not want to pass arguments :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically there is no difference between the two statements. you can use any statement to create an object. **The difference plays its role** when you want to pass the arguments to initialize the constructor. eg:-
Lets consider the case of declaring the scenario. 
for that you will use

```
$model= new User('login');
```

This statement will bind the $model object with a scenario call **'login'** which you can then use for validation purposes.
As you can see since you are not using `()` in case of  `$model = new Users;` SO you cant create a scenario in this statement.
 **BUT** this does not mean that you can never create a scenario now.
To create a scenario using `$model = new Users;` you need to write one more line i.e

```
$model->scenario='login';
```

So from all above  `$model= new User('login');` is equal to

```
$model = new Users;
$model->scenario='login';
```

**Conclusion:-** There is no difference.Both are same till the time you do not want to pass the argument.